# How pause Swiper pagination bullets progress bar animation on hover inside Swiper React carousel

Tags: css, reactjs, progress-bar, swiper.js

For my carousel I'am using [Swiper js](https://swiperjs.com/react) inside my React application.

I am using `autoplay` and `pauseOnMouseEnter` from Swiper core, to pause the autoplay when hovering the carousel. This works as expected.

```
autoplay={{
 delay: 3000,
 disableOnInteraction: false,
 pauseOnMouseEnter: true,
}}
```

I also created progress bars for the pagination bullets. Using `watchSlidesProgress` from Swiper core. With some custom css this also works fine.

The only thing what's missing, when the user hovers over the carousel, it pause the slides. But how do I manage it also pause the progress bar animation on hover the carousel?

Here is a [working sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/swiper-progress-pagination-vbciv) from what I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize swiper with props `onSwiper`.
You can set ref by writing something like this:

```js
const [swiper, setSwiper] = useState<SwiperCore | null>(null);
const carouselSettings = {
    ref: swiper,
    autoplay: {},
}
<Swiper {...carouselSettings} onSwiper={setSwiper}>
```

so after that, you will had prepared `swiper` and you will be able to use `swiper.autoplay` etc.